# How do I fix the following error message in R: "Error in data.frame arguments imply differing number of rows"?

Tags: r, dataframe, web-scraping

I'm ****very**** new to coding in R, and was assigned a task to web scrape. When I attempt to create a data frame (thanks youtube!), I keep getting the error message listed in the above title. Do you spot any obvious errors in my code below or do you have any suggestions for fixing the issue? Thank you!

```
link = "http://www.hockeycentral.co.uk/nhl/records/alltimegoal.php"
page = read_html(link)
rank = page %>% html_nodes('#example :nth-child(1)') %>% html_text()
player = page %>% html_nodes('.text-left:nth-child(2)') %>% html_text()
teams = page %>% html_nodes('.text-left:nth-child(3)') %>% html_text()
goals = page %>% html_nodes(':nth-child(4)') %>% html_text()
games = page %>% html_nodes(':nth-child(5)') %>% html_text()
assists = page %>% html_nodes(':nth-child(6)') %>% html_text()
points = page %>% html_nodes(':nth-child(7)') %>% html_text()
PPG = page %>% html_nodes(':nth-child(8)') %>% html_text()
SHG = page %>% html_nodes(':nth-child(9)') %>% html_text()

nhlcareer = data.frame(rank, player, teams, goals, games, assists, points, PPG, SHG, stringsAsFactors 
= FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `html_table`:

```
library(rvest)

link = "http://www.hockeycentral.co.uk/nhl/records/alltimegoal.php"
page = read_html(link)
table <- page %>% html_table() 
table <- table[[1]]
head(table)

  Rank        Player                                 Team(s) Goals Games Assists Points PPG SHG
1    1 Wayne Gretzky                      EDM, LAK, STL, NYR   894  1487    1963   2857 204  73
2    2   Gordie Howe                               DET, HFD.   801  1767    1049   1850 211  24
3    3  Jaromir Jagr Pit, WSH, NYR, PHI, DAL, BOS, NJD, FLA.   766  1733    1155   1921 217  11
4    4    Brett Hull                 CGY, STL, DAL, DET, PHX   741  1269     650   1391 265  20
5    5 Marcel Dionne                           DET, LAK, NYR   731  1348    1040   1771 234  19
6    6 Phil Esposito                           CHI, BOS, NYR   717  1282     873   1590 246  23
```

The extraction column by column you did returned different column length, for example :

```
> length(player)
[1] 201
> length(rank)
[1] 204
```

As R doesn't know how to put the columns together it returns an error message.